# Why doesn't Ansible take each value separately for this list in the playbook?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have this set up to change the password. But the error message seems like it doesn't understand that there's a loop going on or that it's a list. What's up with my syntax?

Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    uservar:
     - 'testuser'
     - 'testuser2'
     - 'testuser'
    newpassword:
        'success'
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: change user password
      user:
        name: "{{ uservar }}"
        update_password: always
        password: "{{ newpassword|password_hash('sha512') }}"
      loop: "{{ uservar }}"
```

Error message:

```
[WARNING]: The value ['testuser', 'testuser2', 'testuser'] (type list) in a string field was converted to u"['testuser', 'testuser2', 'testuser']" (typestring). If this does not look like what you expect, quote the entire value to ensure it does not change.

failed: [localhost] (item=testuser) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "testuser", "msg": "useradd: invalid user name '['testuser', 'testuser2', 'testuser']'\n", "name": "['testuser', 'testuser2', 'testuser']", "rc": 3}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `item` instead `uservar` in the `name` parameter.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    uservar:
     - 'testuser'
     - 'testuser2'
     - 'testuser'
    newpassword:
        'success'
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: change user password
      user:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        update_password: always
        password: "{{ newpassword|password_hash('sha512') }}"
      loop: "{{ uservar }}"
```